# Why -1 is printed with this context?(Signed char vs unsigned char)

Tags: c++

From what i know it should be implementation-dependent but it returns -1.Why?

```
char ch = 255;
int i = ch;
cout<<i;
return 0;
```

Comment: I would says it depends if `char` is signed or not. (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10fc3d6576f44036)

Comment: You have not stumbled upon an implementation that returns 255 yet.

Comment: Have you tried with GCC and `-funsigned-char`? (I believe MSVC has a corresponding flag, but I can't remember it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char` by default may be signed or unsigned. (implementation dependent)

Minimum range of signed char is -127 to 127 (typically -128 to 127).

If by default char is signed, ch would not be able to accommodate 255(0xFF) and would silently convert it to -1(0xFF). Then you are typecasting it to int and printing so the output is -1.

To avoid this use `unsigned char` explicitly. (Range is atleast 0 to 255)

**4.7  Integral conversions [conv.integral]**

> [3] If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can
>   be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); 
>   otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

Comment: with correct settings, it produce warnings :) (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5ab7d03111595cd)

Comment: Thank god, I always wanted that warning. My rule of thumb is, whenever I want to apply arithmetic on char directly or indirectly, I explicitly use the word signed or unsigned. (Somewhat relaxed version of MISRA C)

Comment: Isn't that quote from the C standard? The question is tagged C++. The relevant part of the C++ standard is `[conv.integral]` (aka `§4.7`).

Comment: @Mankarse Yes you pointed right. I will remove it before it causes any confusion.

Answer (score 3):

`char` might be (and in your case apparently is) a signed type wit a range from -128 to +127.
So `char ch = 255` triggers an overflow which yields an implementation defined result for signed types.